# conditional variables messed up

Tags: python

I am working on the "How old is your dog in human years" problem. My code works for everything except after the dog is 6 years old. After that my software is telling me the dog jumps to 258 years old when I enter 6 for the age.... any help?

```
import traceback

def calculator():
    
    # Get dog age
    age = input("Input dog years: ")

    try:
        # Cast to float
        d_age = float(age)
        
        if d_age <= 1:
            x = 15
        elif d_age <= 2:
            x = 12
        elif d_age <= 3:
            x = 9.3
        elif d_age <= 4:
            x = 8
        elif d_age == 5:
            x = 7.2
        else:
            x = 5 * 7.2 + 7 * (d_age - 5)
            
        h_age = d_age * x
        h_age = round(h_age, 2)
       
       
        print("The given dog age", d_age, "is", h_age, "in human years.")

        # If user enters negative number, print message
        # Otherwise, calculate dog's age in human years
    
        # your code here
        

    except ValueError:
        print(age, "is an invalid age.")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
    
calculator() # This line calls the calculator function
```

Comment: What is the *first* line that doesn't do the correct thing when you use 6?

Comment: That's because (5 * 7.2 + 7 * (6 - 5)) * 6 == 258

Comment: If the age is 6 you hit the `else` sentence and end up with `x=43`.